# Find hash and signature algorithms used in an X.509 certificate signed with RSASSA-PSS

Tags: rsa, public-key, certificates, x.509

I'm trying to understand the new PSS scheme, but having trouble figuring out how to parse it properly.

When receiving a certificate with OID of RSASSA-PSS, how can I know which hash and signing algorithm was used?

Comment: I've removed the second question about RSA encryption from your post, as answering the first one is enough for a very extensive answer. Please ask it separaty and indicate *exactly* what you mean with `rsaEncryption`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Alright, here's a link with the relevant question :https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67101/how-to-identify-rsassa-pss-from-rsaencryption-oid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The ASN.1 module

The OID of RSASSA-PSS [is specified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-C) as below, however, it should only be used as part of an `AlgorithmIdentifier`, which is a SEQUENCE of the OID, followed by the parameters. These parameters are NULL for PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures, but for PSS they *must be present*

Here is the OID:

```
   --
   -- When id-RSASSA-PSS is used in an AlgorithmIdentifier, the
   -- parameters MUST be present and MUST be RSASSA-PSS-params.
   --
   id-RSASSA-PSS    OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-1 10 }
```

and here are the configuration parameters of the algorithm:

```
   -- AlgorithmIdentifier.parameters for id-RSASSA-PSS.
   -- Note that the tags in this Sequence are explicit.
   --
   RSASSA-PSS-params ::= SEQUENCE {
       hashAlgorithm      [0] HashAlgorithm      DEFAULT sha1,
       maskGenAlgorithm   [1] MaskGenAlgorithm   DEFAULT mgf1SHA1,
       saltLength         [2] INTEGER            DEFAULT 20,
       trailerField       [3] TrailerField       DEFAULT trailerFieldBC
   }
```

where the `hashAlgorithm` defines the hash over the data, just like for PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures specify a hash over the data within the message.

However, we still have an undefined `maskGenAlgorithm` of the type with the same name:

```
   MaskGenAlgorithm ::= AlgorithmIdentifier { {PKCS1MGFAlgorithms} }
```

... that's not very helpful, so lets dive deeper:

```
   --
   -- Allowed mask generation function algorithms.
   -- If the identifier is id-mgf1, the parameters are a HashAlgorithm.
   --
   PKCS1MGFAlgorithms    ALGORITHM-IDENTIFIER ::= {
       { OID id-mgf1 PARAMETERS HashAlgorithm },
       ...  -- Allows for future expansion --
   }
```

ah, another hash function is defined here for use with the only defined Mask Generation Function, MGF1.

This - possibly different - hash function is used *within MGF1* and therefore *within PSS* to provide the security required for MGF1.

Finally, a boring little constant for `trailerField`, so that we're complete:

```
   TrailerField ::= INTEGER { trailerFieldBC(1) }
```

## Conclusion

OK, let's recapitulate: the signing algorithm is of course PSS, which depends on a mask generation function MGF1 as only option and a hash over the message. The MGF1 however also has a hash function algorithm assigned to it. Furthermore, you also can indicate a salt length - defaulting to 20 bytes - and a trailer field which currently just has one option.

## Library design options

This message hash defaults to SHA-1, which is not secure for signing data. It also depends on a separate hash function used for MGF1, which *also* defaults to SHA-1. However, for MGF1 the hash function is actually secure. This unfortunately leads to different options for library designers:

1. specify one hash, and let this be the hash for both the message and the MGF1;
2. specify one hash, and let this be the message hash for just the message and keep MGF1 to use SHA-1;
3. always let the user specify both hashes, ignoring the fact that there is a default hash.

Commonly unfortunately either option 1 or option 2 is taken, leaving the developer guessing what hash is used for MGF1.

## Encodings

OK, that was harder than it should be; let instead look at some options for encodings, using the online [Lapo ASN.1 parser](https://lapo.it/asn1js) to decode the manually generated bytes.

First the one specified in the comments of the ASN.1 module within the standard:

```
   30 0D
      06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0A
      30 00
```

which parses to:

```
   SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 rsaPSS (PKCS #1)
      SEQUENCE (0 elem)
```

that's shorter then you'd expect. That's because the PSS parameters consist of a zero element sequence. This may sound weird, but it simply means that the default values are used, i.e. `sha1`, `mgf1SHA1`, a `saltLength` of 20 bytes and of course the only possible `trailerField` identifier, set to 1.

---

You can also specify the exact same structure without default values:

```
  30 3E
     06 09 2A 86 48  86 F7 0D 01 01 0A
     30 31
        A0 0B
           30 09
              06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A
              05 00
        A1 18
           30 16
              06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 08
              30 09
                 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A
                 05 00
        A2 03
           02 01 14
        A3 03
           02 01 01
```

so this explicit encoding shows the actual structure. In above structure it is easy to replace the default parameters by different ones.

```
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 rsaPSS (PKCS #1)
    SEQUENCE (4 elem)
      [0] (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.3.14.3.2.26 sha1 (OIW)
          NULL
      [1] (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.8 pkcs1-MGF (PKCS #1)
          SEQUENCE (2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.3.14.3.2.26 sha1 (OIW)
            NULL
      [2] (1 elem)
        INTEGER 20
      [3] (1 elem)
        INTEGER 1
```

**WARNING:** beware that if a value has a *default*, and if the default value is being used then DER encoding specifies that it *MUST NOT* be encoded. So above is valid BER but not valid DER.

X.509 specifies that the `signature` field (of type `AlgorithmIdentifier` is in the `TBSCertificate` data (TBS means "to be signed", the data that is used in the signature calculation). The `TBSCertificate` data MUST be DER encoded. So above is not valid in a certificate.

---

Of course, as the numbering of SEQUENCE with defaults is explicit, generally it would be more logical to just specify the `[0]` and `[1]` parameters (tag encoding `A0` and `A1`and leave the rest to the default).

So I would expect API's to generate e.g.:

```
  30 1E
     06 09 2A 86 48  86 F7 0D 01 01 0A
     30 11
        A0 0F
           30 0D
              06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01
              05 00
```

which parses as:

```
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 rsaPSS (PKCS #1)
    SEQUENCE (1 elem)
      [0] (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
          NULL
```

for SHA-256 as message hash and the default SHA-1 as MGF1 hash; the rest is set to the default values as well.

---

And, for the ones that uses the same SHA-256 hash for the message and MGF1:

```
  30 3C
     06 09 2A 86 48  86 F7 0D 01 01 0A
     30 2F
        A0 0F
           30 0D
              06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01
              05 00
        A1 1C
           30 1A
              06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 08
              30 0D
                 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01
                 05 00
```

which parses as:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10 rsaPSS (PKCS #1)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    [0] (1 elem)
      SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
        NULL
    [1] (1 elem)
      SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.8 pkcs1-MGF (PKCS #1)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
          NULL
```

this just leaves the salt and trailer field to the default.

## Lamentation on default values

It might not come as a surprise that I'm not a fan of default values. They complicate the hell out of structures like this, and once you've chosen a default, such as SHA-1, it is pretty likely that you'll get into trouble as well, as SHA-1 should be considered broken by now. So we now have a provable secure padding mechanism that defaults to an insecure hash.

A slightly larger algorithm identifier that can be canonically encoded (i.e. has just one representation in bytes) and *explicitly* specifies the algorithms should have been preferred over the ASN.1 hell it is now. As stated above, the DER encoding *requires* to leave out values if they are identical to the default one.